# how to build apk from a ionic framework source code?

Tags: ionic-framework, apk

how do I build apk from an ionic framework source code? which app is used to build the apk?

I tried to build with Cordova but I don't know how to work on a existing code.

Answer (score 0):

1) Install the node.js from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/)

2) open the terminal, npm install -g cordova ionic

3) open the folder of the project from the terminal

4) in the terminal npm install(make sure node.js is insta

5) ionic cordova build android

Comment: Sorry! ionic cordova build can only be run in an Ionic project directory. getting this error, in that project clearly written to build using node.js and cordova, but its not working

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/juq1aiP these are files and folder under the script

Comment: managed to make recognisable as cordova project now getting this error: C:\qt\quotes\Main Files\app\Source Code\Quotes> ionic cordova build android
> ionic-app-scripts build --platform android
'ionic-app-scripts' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[ERROR] Command not found: ionic-app-scripts

Answer (score 0):

Being in the project root directory, run the below command:

```
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```

If successful, connect your android device with Your laptop via USB & make sure, USB debugging enabled. Then try

```
ionic cordova run android
```

Again if you face issues, resubmit the trace. We'll check!